# Writing to specific schemas with RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm using [RPostgreSQL](http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/) to read and write data. Reading from any schema works perfectly, but I'm not able to write to non-public schemas. For example, the following code places a table in the `public` schema, with the name `myschema.tablex`

```
# write dataframe to postgres 
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host="localhost", user="postgres", password="zzzz", dbname="mydatabase", port="5436")
if(dbExistsTable(con,"myschema.tablex")) {
  dbRemoveTable(con,"myschema.vkt_tablex")}
dbWriteTable(con,"myschema.tablex", dataframe, row.names=F)
```

What I want to do, is to place the table `tablex` in the schema `myschema`. I've also tried to name the schema in the connection: `dbname="mydatabase.myschema"` and trying the argument `schemaname` which I saw referred to in an earlier bug.

None of these approaches work, so I'm wondering if there is another method that I can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default schema where objects are created is defined by the [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-OTHER). One way would be to set it accordingly. For instance:

```
SET search_path = myschema, public;
```

I quote the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-OTHER):

> When objects are created without specifying a particular target
>   schema, they will be placed in the first schema listed in the search
>   path. An error is reported if the search path is empty.

You can also make this the [default for a role](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterrole.html), so it is set automatically for every connection made by this role. More:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Thanks @Erwin. If I have five schemas do I need to list them all in my preferred order, or just the one I want `R` to use?

Comment: @celenius: You don't have to list them all. The first schema in your `search_path` that your current role can access will be used for *object creation*. All of them will be *searched* in order for objects until they are found. Ohter schemas are invisible. Special rules apply for system schemas. Much like a search path in a file system. The manual tells it all.

Comment: Note however that schema prefixing a tablename on create should work as well.  i.e.:

create schema test;
create table test.abc (i int);
\d test.abc

Comment: @celenius: Like Scott said: the search_path only provides a default. Schema-qualifying names always overrules the default. Much like a fully qualified path in a file system.

Comment: You could put @ErwinBrandstetter solution in a transaction, e.g., `RPostgres::dbWithTransaction`, so setting the search path is part of your transaction, afterwards it returns back to your ordinary search path.

Answer (score 56):

Use this:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "db", host = "host", port = 5432,
                 user = "user", password = "pwd")
dbWriteTable(con, c("yourschema", "yourtable"), value = yourRdataframe)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

More details: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-db/2011q1/001043.html

Comment: Also works with `dbReadTable`, should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is not longer a valid solution, `RPostgres 1.4.3`

Answer (score 3):

In case a reader is using the newer package `RPostgres` to do this, the code to specify schemas is:

`dbCreateTable(conn = con, name = Id(schema = "yourschema", table = "yourtable"), fields = yourRdataframe)`

Comment: See `help(Id)` in the DBI package, the Id class  refers "to a table nested in a hierarchy (e.g. within a schema)". This can also be used as the name argument in `dbWriteTable`.