# ODBC/DBI in R will not write to a table with a non-default schema in R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, odbc, r-dbi

## The Issue

When trying to write to a table with a non-default schema, `dbWriteTable` in the package DBI, writes to `default.non-default.tablename` rather than writing to `non-default.tablename`. I know that `non-default.tablename` exists because it's showing up in my SSMS database.

#### Reproducible Example/What I've Tried

Create this table in SQL Server with a non-default schema 'guest'. I am placing it in a database called 'SAM':

```
CREATE TABLE guest.MikeTestTable(
[a] [float] NULL,
[b] [float] NULL,
[c] [varchar](255) NULL)

#Create a df to insert into guest.MikeTestTable
df <- data.frame(a = c(10, 20, 30),
                 b = c(20, 40, 60),
                 c = c("oneT", "twoT", "threeT"))

#Create a connection:
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
             .connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};
                                   server=localhost;
                                   database=SAM;
                                   trustedConnection=true;")

#Try to write contents of df to the table using `dbWriteTable`
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con,
                  name = "guest.MikeTestTable",
                  value = df,
                  append = TRUE)

#Create a query to read the data from `"guest.MikeTestTable"`:
q <- "SELECT [a]
  ,[b]
  ,[c]
  FROM guest.MikeTestTable"

##Read the table into R to show that nothing actually got written to the 
##table but that it recognizes `guest.MikeTestTable` does exist:
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, q)

[1] a b c
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I thought this was a weird result so I opened up my SSMS and lo and behold, the table `dbo.guest.MikeTestTable` was created.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try the following: `dbWriteTable(con, c("schema_name","table_name"), df, append = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Trying `dbWriteTable(con, c("guest", "MikeTestTable"), df, append = TRUE)` returns the error: `Error: length(name) == 1 is not TRUE`

Comment: Well, it seems that only works with the [Postgres driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001451/1422451). Try using RODBC package. I see someone [pinged](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI/issues/181) the DBI authors. Is that you?

Comment: We do not want to use the RODBC package because it doesn't play nicely with Travis builds on linux and mac.  I made some comments in the ping of the DBI authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [here](https://github.com/rstats-db/odbc/issues/91#issuecomment-323942559) for the answer

Answer (score 6):

The CRAN release last week (related to the issue @user111417 linked to) resolves this using the new `DBI::Id()` function, where the schema and table names are separate and explicit.  Here's an example.

```
library(magrittr)
table_id <- DBI::Id(
  schema  = "schema_1",
  table   = "car"
)

ds <- mtcars %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("car")

# Create the Table
channel <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv   = odbc::odbc(),
  dsn   = "cdw_cache"
)
result <- DBI::dbWriteTable(
  conn        = channel,
  name        = table_id,
  value       = ds,
  overwrite   = T,
  append      = F
)

DBI::dbGetQuery(channel, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema_1.car")
# Produces `1 32`

DBI::dbExistsTable(channel, table_id)
# Produces: [1] TRUE

DBI::dbDisconnect(channel)
```

(Thanks to Daniel Wood for help in https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/191.)