# Grant SQL permissions in PostgreSQL using R

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm accessing a PostgreSQL database through the R library RPostgreSQL. The following line successfully reads my table into object DF:

`DF <- dbReadTable(conn = con, name = c("my_schema","my_table"))`

However, attempting to write back into the database with the following line throws *ERROR:  permission denied for schema my_schema*:

`dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = c("my_schema", "my_table"), value = DF)`

I've discovered from the question [Writing to specific schemas with RPostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032390/writing-to-specific-schemas-with-rpostgresql) that the solution is to `SET search_path = my_schema, public;`, but I have no idea how to run this from the R Console. I've tried lines such as `dbSendQuery(conn = con, statement = "SET search_path = my_schema, public;")`, and I recognize that setting permissions is not querying at all, but there's not a dbSetPermissions function in RPostgreSQL.

I'm clearly missing something fundamental since the answer to the aforementioned question satisfied the user who asked it, so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Does the user you connected with to Postgres have sufficient permissions to write to the table? I had a similar issue in python that was a db user permission issue.

Comment: The same credentials can modify tables in the database through DBeaver, and I *think* that means the user has sufficient permissions.

Comment: Ah wait that's a good point, I can modify *some* tables in the database through DBeaver. I can *dbWriteTable* to the same schemas that I can modify via DBeaver, and I can't DBeaver-modify the tables to which I can't *dbWriteTable*

Comment: That makes sense - I had to go into postgres user and have a look at the permissions. I'm trying to find a good reference for you but am unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: I think this should help some - part of my issue as well was working with existing versus new objects. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53936/76752